# JabRef and Months

Tags: bibtex, jabref

Anyone that knows why JabRef nowadays seem to use number format for months rather than `jan`, `feb`, etc?

Comment: numbers are needed by biblatex. Do you use the biblatex mode in jabref?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How do I switch these modes?